# series expressed in terms of other series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

Let us assume I have the coefficients $f_n$ and $g_n$ of:
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f_n x^n\quad \text{and}\quad g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}g_n x^n$$
Can I write?:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}g_n x^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}d_kf_{n-k} x^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}d_n x^n\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f_n x^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}d_nx^n f(x)$$
I so, I could calculate $d_k$ from:
$$
g_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}d_kf_{n-k}
$$

Comment: I'm not sure how the heck you are going to calculate d_k.

Comment: cannot I do it by means of a recurrence relationship? I recall I know the general terms $f_n$ and $g_n$.

Comment: It's possible to do as long as $f_0\neq0$

Comment: I confirm $f_0\neq0$

Comment: Maybe you can.  My first impression would be that this would be hard as heck.  Maybe it wouldn't be if you know the gn and fn and it'd be a series of linear equations.  So maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Yea, it's just a system of linear equations. And a triangular one, at that.

Comment: I think you are just calculating $\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}$ which is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}d_nx^n$. But you may run into problem if f(x) is 0 for some $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Sufficient conditions for validity, for the non-trivial case: (1) If $n_f$ is the least $n$ for which $f_n\neq 0$ and $n_g$ is the least $n$ for which $g_n\neq 0$,then $n_f$ exists and $n_f\leq n_g. $ And (2) $f_0\neq 0 \lor x\neq 0. $ And (3) $f(x)\neq 0. $ And (4) $\exists y (|y|>|x|\land$ (the power series for $f(y)$ and $g(y)$ converge)).Condition (4), equivalently, is that the series for $f$ and $g$ converge uniformly on any closed subset of $\{z\in C :|z|<|y|\}$.(The trivial case is $\forall n (g(n)=0)\land f(x)\neq 0.$)